# General formula for this sum $\sum_{i=3}^n \frac{1}{(i-2) i (i+2)} = ?$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

I have been trying to get the general formula for this sum but I am stuck. 
I tried to do a partial fraction but couldn't see any pattern.

$$\sum_{i=3}^n \frac{1}{(i-2) i (i+2)} = ?$$

I need to find the general formula, than to prove it using induction but I can't figure out the formula.

Comment: Was that $=$ sign meant to be there? If so, something's missing on the left of it.

Comment: @J.G. I think it's on purpose. I am sure he wants a formula excluding the iterative sum. I suggest you try to write the result of the first 3 to 5 numbers and see, if it is countable and make an equation out of it.

Comment: @MartinPekár My comment was in reference to a previous version. The question makes sense now.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can rewrite it as:

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{i-2}-\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{i+2}\right)$$

It's a telescopic sum, most elements will cancel each other.

Comment: That's what I did, and Ali found a formula that will hold for n >= 6. But the question asked for n >= 3

Comment: @MohamedTa Then just compute the values for $n=3,4,5$! That isn't too hard...

Answer (score 1):

as @Andronicus showed, it decomposes to three fraction. Now every farction like $\frac{1}{m}$ appears three times, two of them by multiple of $+\frac{1}{2}$ and one time by multiple of $-1$. So they cancel each other, therefore only some terms of first and last remain:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
4\sum_{i=3}^n & = \sum_{i=3}^n (\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{i-2}-\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{i+2}) = \\
& = (\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3-2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4-2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{5-2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{6-2}) \\
& - (\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}) \\
& - (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}) \\
& = (\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(n-1)+2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(n-2)+2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(n-3)+2}) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The above formula is true only for any $n \geqslant 6$, because two middle lines suppose to have no mutual terms.